# Missing attributes in mxcell

Tags: mxgraph

I am working with the mxClient library.

I have the following problem, I need to change only the visual name of my node.

But I am not succeeding.

I have the following code:

var data = "Attributes';

var node = mxUtils.createXmlDocument (). createElement (data);

node.setAttribute ('label', data);

node.setAttribute ('idBD', 123);

/ * here I use some styles and then assign them (left) * /

var v2 = graph.insertVertex (parent, null, node, x, y, 250, 100, 'left');

***Now I just want to change the visual name of my node, which would be 'Attributes'.***

***I have already tried several ways, example:***

***v2.setValue (cell,value) -> But then I lose the previously defined attributes.***

***Thank you***

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you to mimic what is advised in https://jgraph.github.io/mxgraph/docs/js-api/files/model/mxCell-js.html for the `graph.cellLabelChanged` function in that case:

- check if the value is a node
- in that case, update the 'label' node attribute

```js
function setCellLabel(cell, label) {
  if (mxUtils.isNode(cell.value)) {
    cell.value.setAttribute('label', label);
  } else {
    cell.setValue(label);
  }
}
// set the new label
setCellLabel(v2, 'my new label');
```

You should also be able to enrich the mxCell prototype with a new function like

```js
mxCell.prototype.setLabel = function(label) {
  if (mxUtils.isNode(this.value)) {
    this.value.setAttribute('label', label);
  } else {
    this.value = label;
  }
}
// set the new label
v2.setLabel('my new label');
```